# Cannot move image on css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-beaver-4lwid
Hello i was making portfolio and this happened
[this is how it should look like made this with figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCJG4.jpg)
and [my implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecUnu.jpg)
so
my problem is the guy sitting on chair
i cannot move that image i tried to use margin, position, top, left, bottom, right
and none of them worked and when i set it to position: fixed; every layout just breaks
im new to making something with html/css by the way

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";

import "../styles/Home.scss";
import wave from "../assets/images/wave.png";
import sally from "../assets/images/sally.png";

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <img className="wave" src={wave} alt="wave" />
        <div className="short-desc">
          <h1 className="black">Developer</h1>
          <h1>Student</h1>
          <h1 className="black">Something</h1>
        </div>
        <img className="sally" src={sally} alt="sally" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

and this is scss

```
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../assets/images/home_background.png");
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.short-desc {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 30%;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.sally {
  width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: looks like background-size if not background-position alone might help , without a working snippet and image , hard to tell more. ;)

Comment: Please share a codesandbox working snippet.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-beaver-4lwid 
here is codesnadbox

Comment: Give your container a fixed height or use `vh` then use `position: absolute` for your `.sally` image.